# grid layout and how to set style of multiple cells

Tags: css, grid, css-grid

I am using grid layout in css (display: grid). I would like to have rounded borders in all cells in one column (but not in an area). Code below and [linked](https://jsfiddle.net/70r983e6/13/):

```
.myGrid{
  position: absolute;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, calc(100%/5));
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5, calc(100%/5));
  height:100%;
  width: 100%;   
  border: 2px solid pink;
}
.oneColumn { /*how to change style for all individual cells in a column?*/
  grid-row-start: 1;    
  grid-row-end: 6;
  grid-column-start: 3;
  border: 1px solid green;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: yellow;  
}
<div class="myGrid">
  <div class="oneColumn">
  </div>
</div>
```

The outcome of the above code is (obviously) that all cells in column 3 are merged and there is one border around area defined in oneColumn class.

Question: how to set borders (and other styles, such as background color) for all cells in selected area, but not for the area itself?

CSS only, JavaScript is not an option right now.

Thanks!

Comment: Those squares you see in the grid, in the Devtool, are not html elements therefore they can't be styled, they're just there for reference.

Comment: Hi, yes and no. If I specify in .oneColumn parameters: grid-row-start: 3; and  grid-column-start: 3; then I modify style of single grid cell (row 3 and column 3) in the grid. And to avoid manually creating tens of classes I would like to find some automated way (that is not JS).

Comment: You can't style those squares(those are just outlines) you can style the element inside the grid (div.oneColumn) if you want a 5x5 add 10 divs and you'll see them have rounded corners

Comment: OK, clear. I will need to re-design my idea.